# Does the tag "italian-american-english" have a meaning on this site?

Tags: discussion, tags

Does the tag *italian-american-english* have a meaning, for this site?
Is there an English dialect that is called *Italian American English*?

Comment: I created the tag because each question has to have a tag, and this was the first thing I thought of. I believe there is an identifiable form of English which could be labelled thus. The question I asked might offer an example.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could probably argue for a dialect of English called "Italian American English", but it would not be English as spoken by native Italian speakers.  I would not call the latter a dialect because it is not native English.

The Italian American English dialect could be used to describe the particular dialect used by, e.g., Robert De Niro, Al Pacino, etc.

Comment: Is the meaning of _Italian American English_ you reported generally accepted? In other words, would anybody else understand that by _Italian American English_ you mean the dialect spoken by Robert De Niro, or Al pacino?

Comment: As a matter of fact, there is no evidence that the tag was correct, as it doesn't seem that all American people with Italian roots say _gravy_ to mean _sauce_. If we use _Italian-American-English_, we should also use tags like _Chinese-American-English_, _Greek-British-English_ too.